# Why is Koa-Pug returning Not Found in included code?

Tags: koa

I have the following code...

```
// File 1
import {Application2} from "./Application2.mjs";
const app = new Application2();
app.start(()=>{
    console.log("Application has been started")
});


// File 2
import Koa from "koa";
import Router from "koa-router";
import Pug from "koa-pug";
import path from 'path';

const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

export class Application2{
    constructor(){
        console.log(`This thing ${__dirname}/views`)
        this.app = new Koa();
        this.pug = new Pug({
            app: this.app,
            viewPath: `${__dirname}/views`
        });
        const router = new Router();
        router.get("/", function(ctx){
            ctx.render('index');
        })
        this.app.use(router.routes());
    }
    start(callback){
        this.app.listen(PORT, callback);
    }
}
```

When I run this code I see the correct path in the console. However, when I try to go to the site I just see...

[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening, can someone help? It seems to match the examples provided [here](https://github.com/chrisyip/koa-pug)

Answer (score 3):

Ugghhh missed this...

```
 router.get("/", async (ctx) => {
     await ctx.render('index');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```js
router.get('/', function(ctx){
    ctx.render('index')
})
```

**Try This**

```js
my_route.get('/', async (body) => {
    await body.render('index')
})
```